# Recent changes in Location manager behavior?

Tags: android, locationmanager

I develop a running app that use GPS location through LocationManager to deliver a Turn by Turn navigation experience.
Yesterday, ï discovered that I do not receive any location updates when app in background (phone locked) anymore.

This could not be a code regression because none of my previous git commit  work neither. And I know I could receive location updates during last tests few weeks ago.

Then I tested other GPS-based app like Waze and others, but same result : none of them could update my position when going in background (except for GMaps), meaning I have no navigation instruction if my phone is locked. I have tested with other phones Samsung S8, S9, and Asus ... no changes.

Does anybody know if there was a recent changes in LocationManager behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: are you testing with android 8+ by any chance

Comment: Yep I am, but I did some test when android 8.0 released and had no problem at the time. Even if I read some new restrictions here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Comment: well then you know what the issue is

Comment: Okay @TimCastelijns, thanks,  but as I said the issue is more recent than I have Android 8 installed. Moreover, I figured out that another app called "Offline Maps & Navigation" works great even when app is in background. How could they do that if the issue comes from Android 8? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good workaround.

In order to receive GPS location while in background with Android 8.0, we need to create a foreground service that ask for location update and pass it to your activity.

Here is an [example of that.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService)